# How to format json parent child array for json parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Trying to parse the below json output using jquery but the problem that I encountering iswhen trying to parse "pprice" for example an "undefined" error is outputted

```
{ "response": [ {"instances": [ { "instanceID": "000001", "instanceOS": "FreeBSD", "instanceVersion": "10.0", "instanceVendor": "rax", "instanceVendorID": "e28f50b0-7a94-4161-a758-36010c69c8ce", "instanceBit": "64", "instanceSize": "", "instanceEnable": "1", "instanceImg": "fbsd.png" } ], "pricing": [ { "pid": "000001", "pvendor": "rax", "pcpu": "1", "pram": "512MB", "pdisk": "20", "pprice": "0.022", "pband": "", "pssd": "" } , { "pid": "000002", "pvendor": "rax", "pcpu": "1", "pram": "1GB", "pdisk": "40", "pprice": "0.06", "pband": "", "pssd": "" } , { "pid": "000003", "pvendor": "rax", "pcpu": "1", "pram": "2GB", "pdisk": "80", "pprice": "0.12", "pband": "", "pssd": "" } ], "instances": [ { "instanceID": "000002", "instanceOS": "Amazon Linux", "instanceVersion": "2014.03.1", "instanceVendor": "aws", "instanceVendorID": "ami-fb8e9292", "instanceBit": "64", "instanceSize": "", "instanceEnable": "1", "instanceImg": "aws.png" } ], "pricing": [ { "pid": "000004", "pvendor": "aws", "pcpu": "1", "pram": "512MB", "pdisk": "20", "pprice": "0.02", "pband": "", "pssd": "" } , { "pid": "000005", "pvendor": "aws", "pcpu": "1", "pram": "1.7GB", "pdisk": "40", "pprice": "0.06", "pband": "", "pssd": "" } ] } ] }
```

Can successfully parse instance parameters "instanceOS, InstanceVendor" etc, but get undefined with anything inside the "pricing" arrays.

```
var flavors = $.parseJSON(data);

//DISPLAY ELEMENT
$('.distros_bx').fadeIn('slow');//

 //FOREACH LOOP
 $(flavors.response).each(function(i,el) {

 var new_flavor = '<div class="os-id">' + el.instanceID + '</div><div class="os">' +   el.instanceOS + '</div><div class="os-version">' + el.instanceVersion + '</div><div class="os-bit">' + el.instanceBit + '-bit</div><div class="prices_bx">' + el.pprice + '</div>';

$('.distros_bx').append(new_flavor);

 });
```

JSON is valid but perhaps it is not formatted corrected for desired results... Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's because "pricing" is an array like "response" you need to loop it or access by index `el.pricing[0].pprice`.

Comment: @Wilmer so how would I loop through the "pricing" arrays?  No luck with my code...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good json, your `$(flavors.response).each` traverses this:

```
{
   "response":[
      {
         "instances":[],
         "pricing":[],
         "instances":[],
         "pricing":[]
     }
   ]
}
```

You have repeated keys of instances and pricing. Besides, while `instanceID` info is inside instances, `pprice` info is inside pricing

Comment: Ok then, how would I format the JSON so it represents: 
"instances" AS parents and "pricing" children of instances?  

Parent -- FreeBSD, 64-bit, 10.0
Child --- 0.009
Child --- 0.012
Child --- 0.145

Comment: @Dango Well, seems you have more pricings than instances, so that's not a good idea. You should separate instances array from pricings array and have only 1 of each: http://pastebin.com/HpJGTAv7

Comment: The following code are links to the php code and to the mysql data, been trying to get it all working for days but to no avail.  

http://pastebin.com/q1FwsdDT

SQL Data 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a93632/1

Comment: @Dango sorry dont know much about php, but take a look at inner join

Answer (score 0):

After going in circles for 2.5 days decided this json was to ridiculous so opted for a simpler solution.  Now using two seperate json resultsets one for instances and the other for pricing.  Thank you all for the help!